# Differentiation of logarithmic functions.

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZsfc.jpg

If $ y = \log_{10} X + \log_e 10 + \log_x X + \log_{10} 10$, then find $\frac{dy}{dx} $

So I was doing this question and when I got my result it didn't match with the answer given in my book .
My book had the answer as $ 1 / (X \log_{10}) $ where as my answer was $ 1/ (X \log_{10} ) + 1 /10 $

I strongly believe that my answer is right but still can be wrong .
So can somebody please clarify the answer

Can somebody please edit the question on my behalf

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange.  What is $log_x x$?

Comment: Wait a sec I am editing it

Comment: @J.W.Tanner please reply

Comment: Please reply to my question:  what is $\log_X X$?

Answer (score 1):

$\log_X X=1$, so $ y = \log_{10} X + \log_e 10 + \log_x X + \log_{10} 10 = \log_{10}X + $ constant.

Can you take it from there ?